# How about a "BSE-OOS" site?

Tags: discussion

First: "BSE-OOS" is an acronym for "Blender Stack Exchange -  Out of Scope".

I have found a number of situations where a question has been asked that is obviously out of scope of the site as defined in the help page, and yet, for one reason or another, I'd like to provide an answer to the question. One example of this would be a case where an inexperienced user has a problem where the solution amounts to a tutorial, and there I can't find an existing one that would be useful, but I could provide it for the user. A private message facility, like in the forums at Blender-Artists would be one way to do this, but if the Stack-exchange site has a direct contact facility, where I can communicate such a private message to a particular individual, I have yet to discover it. I suppose that one could move a discussion over a particular question to a site like Blender Artists, or one of a host of other forum sites, so these would work, too. Is there some site which would be better for this purpose than others, or would it be worth considering a new site, like "BSE-OOS"?

Comment: One thing you can do in a situation like the one you describe, is [create a chat room](http://blender.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/chat-rooms). This allows discussion to continue between specific users without affecting the rest of the site. If you're so inclined, you can always go as far as to make a complete tutorial and post it on youtube/similar, then link the OP to it (in comments or chat)